# How to save Conda-Spyder-Python setup before Windows 11 reinstallation?

Tags: python, save, conda, spyder, miniconda

I have a hardware problem with my computer and I'm asked to reinstall Windows 11.

However, I don't want to lose all the setup and installation I've done with Miniconda for Spyder and all the packages (In fact, I'm not sure I can redo it the same way! I'm not an expert!).

Would there be a solution to save the total installation and the then to reload it after the reinstallation?

If not, what would be the best alternative?

Thank you